# Share files in Minio

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, minio, file-sharing

I am working on a file manager similar as in demo-https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/material/file-manager/AmazonS3Provider
The backend code is in spring boot and we have stored the files in minio.
I want to share my minio file bucket with some other user by generating a link of minio file bucket. I am using spring boot for writing the code and minio to store the files.

I did not find anything relevant to try so researching about the topic

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
There is ListObjects API. examples are provided.
```

https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/examples/ListObjects.java

```
Presigned URL  is the way to share the objects as per s3 API Spec.
```

https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/examples/GetPresignedObjectUrl.java

```
You could combine these two APIs to achieve the desired functionality.
```

https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc/mc-anonymous-set.html

```
Alternatively you could explore anonymous policies
```

```js
/*
 * MinIO Java SDK for Amazon S3 Compatible Cloud Storage, (C) 2015 MinIO, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import io.minio.ListObjectsArgs;
import io.minio.MinioClient;
import io.minio.Result;
import io.minio.errors.MinioException;
import io.minio.messages.Item;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class ListObjects {
  /** MinioClient.listObjects() example. */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    try {
      /* play.min.io for test and development. */
      MinioClient minioClient =
        MinioClient.builder()
        .endpoint("https://play.min.io")
        .credentials("Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F", "zuf+tfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG")
        .build();

      /* Amazon S3: */
      // MinioClient minioClient =
      //     MinioClient.builder()
      //         .endpoint("https://s3.amazonaws.com")
      //         .credentials("YOUR-ACCESSKEY", "YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY")
      //         .build();

      {
        // Lists objects information.
        Iterable < Result < Item >> results =
          minioClient.listObjects(ListObjectsArgs.builder().bucket("my-bucketname").build());

        for (Result < Item > result: results) {
          Item item = result.get();
          System.out.println(item.lastModified() + "\t" + item.size() + "\t" + item.objectName());
        }
      }

      {
        // Lists objects information recursively.
        Iterable < Result < Item >> results =
          minioClient.listObjects(
            ListObjectsArgs.builder().bucket("my-bucketname").recursive(true).build());

        for (Result < Item > result: results) {
          Item item = result.get();
          System.out.println(item.lastModified() + "\t" + item.size() + "\t" + item.objectName());
        }
      }

      {
        // Lists maximum 100 objects information those names starts with 'E' and after
        // 'ExampleGuide.pdf'.
        Iterable < Result < Item >> results =
          minioClient.listObjects(
            ListObjectsArgs.builder()
            .bucket("my-bucketname")
            .startAfter("ExampleGuide.pdf")
            .prefix("E")
            .maxKeys(100)
            .build());

        for (Result < Item > result: results) {
          Item item = result.get();
          System.out.println(item.lastModified() + "\t" + item.size() + "\t" + item.objectName());
        }
      }

      {
        // Lists maximum 100 objects information with version those names starts with 'E' and after
        // 'ExampleGuide.pdf'.
        Iterable < Result < Item >> results =
          minioClient.listObjects(
            ListObjectsArgs.builder()
            .bucket("my-bucketname")
            .startAfter("ExampleGuide.pdf")
            .prefix("E")
            .maxKeys(100)
            .includeVersions(true)
            .build());

        for (Result < Item > result: results) {
          Item item = result.get();
          System.out.println(
            item.lastModified() +
            "\t" +
            item.size() +
            "\t" +
            item.objectName() +
            " [" +
            item.versionId() +
            "]");
        }
      }
    } catch (MinioException e) {
      System.out.println("Error occurred: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```